# Passing a List of IP address to get port scanned in python (libnmap)

Tags: python, security, nmap, port-scanning

I am working on a python script which basically scans port on a IP address ,& I am using the `libnmap` library to do so , referring the docs at : https://libnmap.readthedocs.org/en/latest/process.html#purpose-of-libnmap-process

what i am hoping to do is read a external file which contains list of IP address to be scanned and pass each of the IP address as :

```
file_object = open(file_containg_ip_to_be_port_scanned, r)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        report = do_scan("pass_ip_here", "-sV")
        if report:
            print_scan(report)
```

how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want something like this:

```
with open('ip_list.txt') as f:
    for ip in f.read().splitlines():
        report = do_scan(ip, "-sV")
        if report:
            print_scan(report)
```

Comment: You should make sure that each line in the file contains only `ip` or extracting only `ip` if that's not the case by stripping and removing extra characters...like for instance `line.strip()`...

Comment: Valid. I think a better way to do it would be to use `f.read().splitlines()` instead of `f.readlines()`. Edited, thanks.